# How to detect stuttering programmatically?

Tags: android, detection, frame-rate

When I look at the ListView and scroll it, I know it's stuttering if it is obvious. But sometimes when it is not so obvious, it make me confused whether the scrolling stuttering or not? In other words, how can I detect whether frames have lost?

Is there a way to detect such stuttering programmatically? I have read ["How to discover if OpenGL ES frame rate is stuttering - without Instruments?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304913/how-to-discover-if-opengl-es-frame-rate-is-stuttering-without-instruments), but I don't think it's appropriate for 2D views such as ListView in Android.

Comment: What I've noticed when dealing with my ListViews is that they "stutter" every time that the Garbage Collector runs. This makes sense since it means that the system is spending time doing something else other than rendering your views. You can check LogCat to see if this is happening in your case as well.

Comment: It's indeed a clue but not works for me. GC hasn't happened while i feel stuttering does.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it (I haven't tested it), is to extend the ListView you have, override the `draw` or `onDraw` method, and check how many times it is called within a second. Anything below ~25 frames per second means it's stuttering.

Also it's worth nothing that there are almost always optimizations that you can do on your ListView to avoid stuttering on all phones (hint: check the view reuse in your adapter)

Comment: FPS lower than 25 doesn't mean stuttering has happened. Thinking about scroll Home screen slowly, for sure fps is low even lower than 10, but you won't notice stuttering.    And we can let SHOW_FPS=true in ViewRoot.java to show current fps.

Comment: Actually, scrolling the Home screen slowly will still render the maximum fps it can, even if you scroll it slowly.

Comment: OK, but why is 25? Is it a practical or theoretical value?

Comment: 25fps is supposedly what the human eye perceives. Of course, it's different for everyone of us, but only slightly. This is approximately what most movies use too.